# Pandas/Matplotlib date tick marks disappear in subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm having some issues with tick marks disappearing when I apply a locator and formatter to them. I want a plot with multiple subplots that share the same x axis, so only the bottom subplot would have the labels, but all subplots should have labels. Below is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.DataFrame(np.absolute(np.random.randn(100)), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100, freq='M'))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1,sharex=True,figsize=(8,10),dpi=300,tight_layout=True)
df.plot.area(ax=axes[1],legend=False)
```

So far so good. Looking at the fig at this point, you can see ticks and year labels. (Note I'm just adding one plot in this example, but the behavior is the same if I have multiple plots and multiple columns.) But I'd like to place ticks at every month, like [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html)
.

```
years = mdates.YearLocator()   # every year
months = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month
yearsFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y')

for ax in axes:
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
```

When I do that, things get weird:

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYUBp.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: In general matplotlib.dates locators and formatters are incompatible with pandas plots. I think I've written this comment below some 20 questions already, so I'm a bit tired of finding the corresponding answers again.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this can be fixed by adding "x_compat=True" to the plot function call:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7Xux.png)

See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13/visualization.html. Not sure why, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding: 
`plt.xticks(pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100, freq='M'))`

Comment: That doesn't seem to help here, sorry. It just creates a new plot.